# Can't send POST message over Https

Tags: java, php, android, post, https

I have a simple android app that needs to send a message to my `PHP` server, which will return some data back. I am able to get the data returned from the server, but I can't send any. It's probably something stupid, but I can't figure it out. Note that the url here isn't the real url.

```
public void addUser(User user, String password) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL("https://someuser.c9users.io/service.php");
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // set Timeout and method
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setReadTimeout(7000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
    conn.setRequestProperty("op", "adduser");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("username",user.getUserName());
    conn.setRequestProperty("email",user.getEmail());
    conn.setRequestProperty("password", password);
    if(user.getBirthDate() != null)
        conn.setRequestProperty("birthdate", user.getBirthDate().toString());
    if(user.getProfImage() != null)
        conn.setRequestProperty("profile_image", "some path to img");

    //conn.connect(); if I leave the code it does NoFileFoundException. why?
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    String result="";
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        result += inputLine;
    }

}
```

my php code:

```
function print_post_get() {
    echo "post&get vals: ";
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        echo $key.":".$value." \n";
    }
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
        echo $key.":".$value." \n";
    }
}

//print all post and get
print_post_get();
//get method form post
if(empty($_POST['op']))
die('no operation?');

switch($_POST['op']) {

    case 'adduser':
        $retval = adduser();
        if($retval) //couldn't add user
            echo $retval;
        break;

    case 'removeuser': 
        $retval = removeuser();
        if($retval)
            echo $retval;
        break;
    case 'getuser':
        $retval = getuser();
        echo $retval;
        break;
    default:
        echo "unknow op.";
        break;
}
```

Comment: you mean to say you are able to do GET requests but not able to POST data ?

Comment: Does it require you to have any client certificates also?

Comment: you did not add data into output stream..

Comment: use `PrintWriter.write` method to send to output stream.

Comment: I wan's able to send GET or POST

Comment: Any stack trace available ? unComment `conn.connect();` else it is not possible to send the message.

Comment: How do I send data? isn't done with ` conn.setRequestProperty` ? how should I send data in such a way that each data peace will be associated with a property?

Comment: Please check the forum before posting questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: off the post note : I would really suggest using Retrofit or volley. it not only keeps your code clean n makes your communciation faster but also makes debugging easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem. I found `setRequestProperty` adds to your headers, not the POST body. But the

```
conn.setDoOutput(true)
```

allows you to connect to the

```
outStream = conn.getOutputStream()
```

Now you can create the POST data with a `android.net.Uri.Builder`.

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
    .appendQueryParameter("username",user.getUserName())
    .appendQueryParameter("email",user.getEmail());
```

Write to the stream, the `getEncodedQuery()`

```
try (OutputStream outStream = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(outStream, "UTF-8"))) {
    String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
    writer.write(query);
 }
```

Now you can POST your request with `conn`.

Comment: so what is the point of `setRequestProperty` ? and  Android studio says: `cannot resolve method 'getEncodedQuery()' `

Comment: @user2554080 Make sure you have created the builder prior to the call. It is this method - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getEncodedQuery(). setRequestProperty only sets header-fields, while appendQueryParameter can be used as the POST payload.

Comment: so do I need `setRequestProperty` at all?

Comment: . The function `getEncodedQuery()` isnt part of the builder class as shown in my documentation on Uri.Builder

Comment: see: [link] ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html)

Comment: are you even sure this is good for POST ?? because it puts the parameters on the url....

Comment: @user2554080 Du you do   `conn.setRequestMethod("POST");`?

Comment: @user2554080 Added the build():Uri call.

Comment: @user2554080 The BufferedWriter writer is not writing to the query string. Does php see a POST request? Does it set anything in $_POST?

Comment: @user2554080 Also keep in mind that it is a lot easier to debug if you start with a http connection so you can user regular networking tools to see what is actually sent and recieved.

Comment: I'm using cloud 9 which is very comfortable to develop with, and it has https only. Any way, the problem was the line of the timeout - that apparently  was reached during the time of debugging. The weird thing now is that on the server I have in POST parameter named `?op`, and not `op` ??? why?

Comment: @user2554080 I use a local apache/php server for debugging purposes. Maybe that is an option for you too.  The ?op is probably worthy of a separate question.